# import sample StorageProvider Error

Tags: android, android-studio

this is my first time in android studio to import samples.
I tried to import Storage Provider.
after importing it, the project does not successfully compiled, it gives me an error.
In line 48 MainActivity.java android studio doesn't recognize StorageProviderFragment class.

I think it will be easy to solve it, may be it is a library or another project which it is depends on, but google did not check codes before/after publishing it  (problem like this since working days with eclipse till now).

so how to fix this in android studio, or where is the rest of code? where can I find StorageProviderFragment class? should I

note: gradle build successfully.

android platform api: 6

android sdk: 24.3.4

android studio: 1.3.2

By using sdk manager I downloaded android-23 samples and then I searched in its folder and did not find the required class, also I searched in /sdk/samples for all samples previously downloaded (10,18,19,20,21 and 23)  for current and old releases, also didn't find the class.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing there was an update to the sample code that didn't make it all the way through. I could get it to run by changing

```
StorageProviderFragment
```

to

```
MyCloudFragment
```

Good luck.

Kaamel